# How to Convert COCO Json to YOLOv8 segmentation format

Tags: object-detection, image-segmentation, yolo, yolov8

```
def convert_coco_to_yolov8(coco_file):

    with open(coco_file) as f:
        coco = json.load(f)


    images = coco['images']
    annotations = coco['annotations'] 
    categories = {cat['id']: cat['name'] for cat in coco['categories']}

    
    os.makedirs('labels', exist_ok=True)

 
    for image in tqdm(images, desc='Converting images'):
        image_id = image['id']
        filename = image['file_name']



        label_filename = filename.split('.png')[0]
        label_path = os.path.join('labels', f'{label_filename}.txt')
        with open(label_path, 'w') as f:

            for ann in annotations:
                if ann['image_id'] != image_id:
                    continue

                img_width = image['width']
                img_height = image['height']

                xmin, ymin, width, height = ann['bbox']
              
                xmax = xmin + width
                ymax = ymin + height
                xcen = (xmin + xmax) / 2
                ycen = (ymin + ymax) / 2
                # xcen = (xmin + xmax) / 2 / img_width
                # ycen = (ymin + ymax) / 2 / img_height
                w = xmax - xmin
                h = ymax - ymin
                label = categories[ann['category_id']]
                label_id = ann['category_id']
             
            

                segmentation_points_list = []
                for segmentation in ann['segmentation']:
                    segmentation_points = [str(point / img_width) for point in segmentation]
                    segmentation_points_list.append(' '.join(segmentation_points))
                segmentation_points_string = ' '.join(segmentation_points_list)


                                

             
                line = '{} {} {} {} {} {}\n'.format(label_id, xcen / img_width, ycen / img_height, w / img_width, h / img_height, segmentation_points_string )
                f.write(line)
```

the script is getting the labels but when i train for YOLOv8 the labels are seems wrong ,I need to convert a coco json to YOLOV8 txt file . label should contain segmentation also. Note my JSON file have different image size for all images

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

I have loaded all the images in images/all_images directory. I used coco .json annotations differently for train/test/val. You can change accordingly. Make sure to create directory yourself.

```html
import os
import json
import shutil

# load json and save directory for labels train/val/test
coco_file = 'labels/val.json'
save_folder = 'labels/val'

# 0 for truck, 1 for car
category = 1

#source of all the images and destination folder for train/test/val
source_path = "images/all_images"
destination_path = "images/val"


# Use os.listdir() to get a list of filenames in the folder
file_names = os.listdir(source_path)



with open(coco_file) as f:
    coco = json.load(f)

images = coco['images']
annotations = coco['annotations'] 
categories = {cat['id']: cat['name'] for cat in coco['categories']}

#os.makedirs(save_folder, exist_ok=True)

for ann in annotations:
    image = next(img for img in images if (img['id'] == ann['image_id']))
    if (image["file_name"] not in file_names):
        continue
    
    width, height = image['width'], image['height']
    x_coco, y_coco, width_coco, height_coco = ann['bbox']
    
   
    
    category_id = ann['category_id']

    image_id = ann['image_id']

    filename = image['file_name']
    label_filename = filename.split('.jpg')[0]
    label_path = os.path.join(save_folder, f'{label_filename}.txt')
    with open(label_path, 'a') as f:

        segmentation_points_list = []
        for segmentation in ann['segmentation']:
            # Check if any element in segmentation is a string
            if any(isinstance(point, str) for point in segmentation):
                continue  # Skip this segmentation if it contains strings

            segmentation_points = [str(float(point) / (width-1) if i % 2 == 0 else float(point) / (height-1)) for i, point in enumerate(segmentation)]
            segmentation_points_list.append(' '.join(segmentation_points))
            segmentation_points_string = ' '.join(segmentation_points_list)
            line = '{} {}\n'.format(category, segmentation_points_string)
            f.write(line)
            segmentation_points_list.clear()
    image_source = source_path + f'/{image["file_name"]}'
    shutil.copy(image_source, destination_path)
```

```html
import os
import json
import shutil

# load json and save directory for labels train/val/test
coco_file = 'labels/val.json'
save_folder = 'labels/val'



#source of all the images and destination folder for train/test/val
source_path = "images/all_images"
destination_path = "images/val"


# Use os.listdir() to get a list of filenames in the folder
file_names = os.listdir(source_path)

with open(coco_file) as f:
    coco = json.load(f)

images = coco['images']
annotations = coco['annotations'] 
categories = {cat['id']: cat['name'] for cat in coco['categories']}

#os.makedirs(save_folder, exist_ok=True)

for ann in annotations:
    image = next(img for img in images if (img['id'] == ann['image_id']))
    if (image["file_name"] not in file_names):
        continue
    #print(f"image in annotations =   {type(image['id'])}")
    width, height = image['width'], image['height']
    x_center = (ann['bbox'][0] + ann['bbox'][2] / 2) / width
    y_center = (ann['bbox'][1] + ann['bbox'][3] / 2) / height
    bbox_width = ann['bbox'][2] / width
    bbox_height = ann['bbox'][3] / height
    category_id = ann['category_id']
    image_id = ann['image_id']

    filename = image['file_name']
    label_filename = filename.split('.jpg')[0]
    label_path = os.path.join(save_folder, f'{label_filename}.txt')
    with open(label_path, 'a') as f:

        segmentation_points_list = []
        for segmentation in ann['segmentation']:
            # Check if any element in segmentation is a string
            if any(isinstance(point, str) for point in segmentation):
                continue  # Skip this segmentation if it contains strings

            segmentation_points = [str(float(point) / width) for point in segmentation]
            segmentation_points_list.append(' '.join(segmentation_points))
            segmentation_points_string = ' '.join(segmentation_points_list)
            line = '{} {}\n'.format(categories, segmentation_points_string)
            f.write(line)
            segmentation_points_list.clear()
    image_source = source_path + f'/{image["file_name"]}'
    shutil.copy(image_source, destination_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below below code for the desired conversion...

```
from ultralytics.data.converter import convert_coco

convert_coco(labels_dir='path/to/coco/annotations/', use_segments=True)
```

For more details, please follow the [**Port or Convert Label Formats**](https://docs.ultralytics.com/datasets/segment/#adding-your-own-dataset).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the label format used in this script:

```
line = '{} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(label_id, x_center, y_center, w_box, h_box, segmentation_points_str)
```

For instance segmentation format use this: class x1 y1 x2 y2 ... xn yn. So I recommend changing this line to:

```
line = '{} {}'.format(label_id, segmentation_points_str)
```

Instance segmentation label format: https://docs.ultralytics.com/datasets/segment/